# Using a delay in for loop -- Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, delay

Im trying to make a simple startup application to learn Swift. I am new to programming in general and I am in a little over my head. This bit of code is meant to highlight (change the background color) of a certain UIButton and then change it back. At first I added a delay of 0.5 seconds to each action but then I learned a IBAction only updates once at end of execution?. So I then added the delay to increment each time. The code works for the first 3 or 4 loops but then acts up and does not delay correctly. Please help, Thanks

```
func SSSays(clicks:Int) {

    sPattern.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(4) + 1))
    var wait = 0.5


    for button in sPattern {

        if(button == 1) {
            wait = wait + 0.5
            self.delay(wait) {self.BBB.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: (102/255), green: (178/255), blue: (255/255), alpha: (1))}

            wait = wait + 0.5
            self.delay(wait) { self.BBB.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() }


        } else if(button == 2) {

            wait = wait + 0.5
            self.delay(wait) {self.RBB.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: (255/255), green: (153/255), blue: (153/255), alpha: (1))}

            wait = wait + 0.5
            self.delay(wait) {self.RBB.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() }


        } else if(button == 3){

            wait = wait + 0.5
            self.delay(wait) {self.GBB.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: (153/255), green: (255/255), blue: (204/255), alpha: (1)) }

            wait = wait + 0.5
            self.delay(wait) {self.GBB.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor() }


        } else if(button == 4){

            wait = wait + 0.5
            self.delay(wait) {self.OBB.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: (255/255), green: (204/255), blue: (255/255), alpha: (1)) }
            wait = wait + 0.5
            self.delay(wait) {self.OBB.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor() }

        }
    }



}




func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))),dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look into animation functions. They were created for this reason and will greatly simplify your code. Here's a basic one that you can play with to get you started:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
            self.BBB.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            }, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options:.allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
                self.BBB.backgroundColor = .red
            }, completion: nil)
```

You can then add in code for the completion block to handle additional code once that duration of the animation completes if you see fit.

`options: []` can take parameters such as Autoreverse, Repeat, etc. to give you additional effects.